# Stop word containing spans from wrapping?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm having some problems with a word that contains `span`'s from wrapping.

The code below looks quite complicated but all it's doing is adding coloured dots to all the i's in the word "imagination".

```
<h2>The&nbsp;Clore&nbsp;Prize&nbsp; <span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(255, 211, 0);">i</span>mag<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(0, 179, 223);">i</span>nat<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(238, 65, 34);">i</span>on&nbsp;lab</h2>
```

The only problem I have is that the word wraps at the spans. How can I stop it doing that? I don't want to change the way the coloured dots are added.

This is what happens:

[image]

If I put a no wrap on the h2 then it does this (with the word going off the screen):

[image]

It's on [this page](http://www.ioi.london/latest/the-clore-prize-imagination-lab/).

Comment: Can't you just remove the newline break and whitespace? See: https://jsfiddle.net/9r7vg92c/ Alternatively, you could always add `white-space: nowrap`...

Comment: Independent of your question you can improve the overview by using css classes. https://jsfiddle.net/0meacfx1/

Comment: @JoshCrozier Sorry that was just a mistake adding the question.

Comment: _"The only problem I have is that the word wraps at the spans."_ Not certain interpret correctly ? Can describe "the word wraps" ?

Comment: @Rob Even in your updated question you still have a standard space character: `…&nbsp; <span…` You will need to remove it, replace it with a non-breaking space `&nbsp;`, or apply `white-space: nowrap;` to your `h2`. It's a good idea to move your styles into a stylesheet as well.

Comment: What is the expected wrapping behavior? First you implied you don't want it to wrap at the spans, then you imply you don't want the entire word to go offscreen (instead of wrapping), which seems contradictory.

Comment: @gfullam My guess is that he wants the whole word to wrap to a new line rather than breaking up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove all whitespace in the word, or use `white-space: nowrap`:

```html
<h2>These words will wrap. <span style="white-space:nowrap"><span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(255, 211, 0);">i</span>longwordlongwordlongwordlongwordlongwordlongwordlongwordlongword<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(0, 179, 223);">i</span>nat<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(238, 65, 34);">i</span>on</span> Wrap</h2>
```

In general it's better to separate your CSS from the HTML, but this looks like one-off code that you're unlikely to reuse elsewhere in the document so inlining it with style attributes may be appropriate here.

Comment: Just updated my question to show what happens with that. It's on this page when reducing the page down - http://www.ioi.london/latest/the-clore-prize-imagination-lab/

Comment: Updated answer to accommodate words that you do want to wrap.

Comment: So just to be clear, you've added a no wrap span around all the other spans?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove the whitespace

HTML will condense white space, including newlines and tabs, into a single space between "words" and inline elements (some exceptions apply).

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.1

```
<h2>The&nbsp;Clore&nbsp;Prize&nbsp;<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(255, 211, 0);">i</span>mag<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(0, 179, 223);">i</span>nat<span style="text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(238, 65, 34);">i</span>on&nbsp;lab</h2>
```

But the better way to do this is to move your inline styles into a stylesheet. You can even rely on semantic HTML `u` tags and remove the hard-coded non-breaking space characters for cleaner markup.

```css
h2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.yellow {
  color: rgb(255, 211, 0);
}
.blue {
  color: rgb(0, 179, 223);
}
.red {
  color: rgb(238, 65, 34);
}
```

```html
<h2>The Clore Prize <u class="yellow">i</u>mag<u class="blue">i</u>nat<u class="red">i</u>on lab</h2>
```

Comment: Sorry that was just a mistake adding the question.

Comment: Even in your updated question you still have a standard space character: `…&nbsp; <span…` You will need to remove it, replace it with a non-breaking space `&nbsp;`, or apply `white-space: nowrap;` to your `h2`. It's a good idea to move your styles into a stylesheet as well.

Comment: @gfullum I'm sure I'm just copying the code into my question incorrectly but this is the page it's on - http://www.ioi.london/latest/the-clore-prize-imagination-lab/... when it's reduced down to mobile size.

Comment: I can't view that page from this computer (and links to external sites are bad for posterity). You need to provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.